# Difference between medium and long sized hyphen?

Tags: hyphenation

Is there any difference between a 'long' and a 'medium' sized hyphen?  (I don't think so, but I am just checking to make sure)

We all know the very short line, namely, the 'dash': -

Then there is also the hyphen, which I just recently found two versions of:

1. A medium hyphen
2. A long hyphen

[image]

For comparison, I added the the dash to the right.

Answer (score 2):

You have your terminology confused. What you call a dash is traditionally called an 'en dash', and the longer line an 'em dash' (because, in traditional printers' metal type, the letter **m** is twice as wide as **n**.

The hyphen is only used for joining words (like half-pint) or marking a division in a word when there isn't room for all of it at the end of a line.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash